# Java - how to divide an integer into 5 random parts

Tags: java, random, integer, logic

I'm working on an android graphics app, and at some point in the code, I need to divide lets say, a rectangle's width into 5 random sizes.

I have my randomintegerfunction(int min, int max) in my activity, but that can help me divide it into 2 parts.

How do I go about dividing an integer, lets say 100, into 5 random parts, so that the first one or two parts arent always the biggest, then I subdivide for the third, fourth and fifth parts?

Right now, I am know I can try to implememt it using my random integer generator,but the issue, I think is that I'd have to use some forced divisions, like dividing the first 70%  of the integer into 2 parts, then dividing the remaining 20% into two parts, to make a total of 5 parts, but such a method would always make the first part be bigger than the fifth part, which I'd like to avoid...to make it truly random.

What I'd like, for example...

the first part to potentially be 7,
second part 25, 
third part 5, 
fourth part 40, 
fifth/last/remaining part 23. To add up to 100 (or any integer).

I am not sure about how to write the logic of such a function...so please if you have any ideas of how to implement a function that randomly divides an integer into 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 truly random sizes/parts, please enlighten me!

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I don't get the part `so that the first one or two parts arent always the biggest`. Can't you just change the order randomly after you divided that number into parts?

Comment: i would use Random to get 4 different numbers in the range 1-99 and use them as the "cut points" of the whole integer. `e.g. suppose i got (2,25,40,90)- the widths would be (100-90, 90-40, 40-25, 25-2, 2-0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could randomly select from the amount remaining.

```
int[] nums = new int[5];
int total = 100;
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length-1; i++) {
    nums[i] = rand.nextInt(total);
    total -= nums[i];
}
nums[nums.length-1] = total;
Arrays.sort(nums);
```

This will select a random number and ensure the sum is always the same. The last `sort` ensures they are in ascending order.

Comment: Worked perfectly, once I removed the -1 from the nums.length-1 in the for loop definition. Without removing the -1, it didnt assign a value to the fourth position of the array. Thanks for your flexible solution!

Comment: @Hideyoshi It should assign to the `nums[4]` position the remaining `total` after the loop.

Comment: I tested it as is (with the nums.length-1), and the fourth element of the array was consistently 0. It would always be like 23,12,34,0,5... until I removed the -1

Answer (score 1):

A simple algorithm is to put the numbers 1-99 into a list, shuffle them, and take the first 4 elements as your "split points", i.e. positions at which to divide the number range.

```
List<Integer> splitPoints =
    IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 99)
        .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
Collections.shuffle(splitPoints);
splitPoints.subList(4, splitPoints.size()).clear();
Collections.sort(splitPoints);
```

Now, you have 4 randomly-placed split points. The ranges go from:

- 0 -> `splitPoints.get(0)`
- `splitPoints.get(0)` -> `splitPoints.get(1)`
- ...
- `splitPoints.get(3)` -> 100.

Answer (score 0):

Take four numbers from below range:

```
4 to n-1
```

And then divide each number by four .

And fifth number to be `n - (sum of other four)`.

Where n is 100 in the given case..

Again this is one way of implementation and there are hundred of ways to implement it

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to do this and to keep proper distribution - looks like this.

1) In general cases. You need divide line into N parts.

```
generate N-1 doubles [0,1], add 0 and 1, and sort them -> x[i] = {0, ..., 1}
N-1 point divide line into N parts -> 0=x[0]..x[1]; x[1]...x[2]; ... x[N]..x[N+1]=1
scale each part to proper size -> len[i] = (x[i+1]-x[i])*total_length
cast to int if needed
```

2) In case when you need large Objects and small gaps - split you length with desirable proportion, like 70% for objects and 30% for gaps. Or generate it nextDouble(0.2)+0.2 for [0.2,0.4) range for gaps. Then use proposed algorithm twice.